# awk filter lines from log by time

Tags: awk

I have logs with the following structure:

```
2016-07-06 06:53:35,764 INFO   com.myown.filter.BaseLoggingFilter log 777 * Server responded with a response on thread ajp-bio-8009-exec-1
777 < 501
777 < Content-Type: application/json

2016-07-06 07:00:00,820 INFO   com.myown.filter.BaseLoggingFilter log 778 * Server has received a request on thread ajp-bio-8009-exec-2
778 > GET https://webservice/endpoint
778 > accept: */*
778 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
778 > authorization: ***[MASKED]***
778 > connection: Keep-Alive
778 > content-length: 0
778 > host: webservice
778 > user-agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java 1.5)
```

I'm looking for a way to filter these entries by time. Let's say I want to have all entries before 07 AM.

I managed to write the following:

```
cat webservice.log | awk '$2~/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/ && $2 < "07:00:00"'
```

This will only print out the lines containing date and time.

```
2016-07-06 06:53:35,764 INFO   ...
```

Now I would also want to include the other lines corresponding to the request.

I've tried working with variables, but I can't quite figure it out. The below code fragment I botched together by googling, but it isn't working.

```
cat webservice.log | awk '$2~/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/ && $2 > "00:00:00" {p=1}
$2~/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/ && $2 < "07:00:00" {p=0}
p {print $0}'
```

What I expect this code to be doing:

So, when the second field is a time, and it is larger than 00:00:00, p=1 and the line will be printed. If for the following lines no date is found, they are also just printed (because p is still 1). If a line occurs where the second field is a time, but it is larger than 07:00:00, p will become 0, and the lines will stop being printed.

But this isn't working. Probably something wrong with my understanding of how AWK works.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming #of lines after matched line are constant, you can use egrep with pattern like ` 0[0-6]:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}, `. So final command could look like `egrep -A5 ' 0[0-6]:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}, ' webservice.log` where 5 represents #of lines to print and 'A' signifies 'After' the match

Comment: Yeah that's the problem. The number of lines is not constant (like in my example).

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  Rather than asking a question it seems to be an answer.  Does it **not** actually work despite being described as working?  If so, you should say that and what is wrong.

Comment: Hi MAP, I'm unable to achieve what I want to achieve. The last piece of code does not actually work. I've edited the question to better reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your log entries are separated by blank lines.  We can use that to separate one entry from the next:

```
$ awk -F'[ :]+' '$2<7' RS="" logfile
2016-07-06 06:53:35,764 INFO   com.myown.filter.BaseLoggingFilter log 777 * Server responded with a response on thread ajp-bio-8009-exec-1
777 < 501
777 < Content-Type: application/json
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[ :]+'`

  This sets the field separator to any number of spaces or colons.   With this setting, the first field is the date, the second field is the hour, the third is minutes, etc.
- `$2<7`

  This prints any record for which the hour field, $2, is less than 7.
- `RS=""`

  This tells awk to read in a blank-line-separated paragraph as one *record*.  Thus, a single print causes the entire entry (record) to be printed out, not just its first line.